# Difficulty implementing limit to how many integers print on each line C++

Tags: c++, loops, printing, integer, limit

I have seen this question around, but I am having difficulty implementing some of the solutions into my own code.

The program being worked on finds all the prime numbers in an array and times how long it takes to find all the prime numbers. One of the stipulations though is making the program print only 10 numbers per line. I have tried a couple different methods to get this to work, but none of them print how I need them to. Here is the current code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

static const int N = 1000;

int main()
{


    int i, a[N];

    clock_t start = clock();

    for (i = 2; i < N; i++) a[i] = i;
    for (i = 2; i < N; i++)
        if (a[i])
            for (int j = i; j*i < N; j++) a[i*j] = 0;

    start = clock() - start;

    for (i = 2; i < N; i++)
        if (a[i]) cout << " " << i;
            if ((i = 1) % 10 == 0)
                cout << "\n";

    printf("\nIt took %d clicks (%f seconds) to find all prime numbers.\n", start, ((float)start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm sure this is a simple mistake on my own part, or maybe I dont have the proper understanding on how this works. If anyone can shed some light on the subject it would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a new counter, to count the number of primes found.

```
int primes = 0;
for (i = 2; i < N; i++) {
    if (a[i]) {
       primes++;
       cout << " " << i;
       if ( primes % 10 == 0)
            cout << "\n";
     }
 }
```

Comment: It works perfectly! I dont know how to thank you enough.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i = 2; i < N; i++)
    if (a[i]) cout << " " << i;
        if ((i = 1) % 10 == 0)
            cout << "\n";
```

What this snippet does is not at all what you want it to do. If your whitespace is any indication, it looks like you expect this all to be nested in the same for loop. However, it's actually processed like this:

```
for (i = 2; i < N; i++) if (a[i]) cout << " " << i;

if ((i = 1) % 10 == 0) cout << "\n";
```

In other words, two completely separate statements. The first one goes through every element of `a[i]` and outputs them with a space. When that loop is done to completion, the second statement then checks a condition and adds a newline (that check is also broken, but I'll get into that later).

In order to break after every tenth element, the newline check needs to be processed for each element, or at least each element *printed*, rather than at the end.

So as written, what you seem to expect would actually be something like:

```
for (i = 2; i < N; i++) {
    if (a[i]) cout << " " << i;
    if ((i = 1) % 10 == 0)
        cout << "\n";
}
```

The braces `{ }` are important here, since they ensure that *all the enclosed statements* are part of the for loop and processed for each iteration, not just the single statement immediately following it.

Which brings up the second issue: That newline check does not do what you think it does. From your explanation, what you want is for the check to trigger on every tenth value printed, and add a newline. However, `if ((i = 1) % 10 == 0)`…doesn't do that. At all.

Rather than triggering on every tenth value, all `if ((i = 1) % 10 == 0` does is set `i` to 1 (which will really break your for loop) and then never trigger since `i = 1` will always return `1` anyway. It's just a convoluted way to do exactly what you don't want.

As [Amadeus mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967280/64918), one easy way to implement this is just to use a counter that increments every time you print a value, and test against that instead:

```
for (i = 2; i < N; i++) {
    if (a[i]) {
        cout << " " << i;
        primes++;
        if (primes % 10 == 0)
            cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Again, note the braces enclosing the three statements for the `if (a[i])` clause. This ensures the increment and newline check only happen every time a value is actually printed, rather than for every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this in depth for me. I managed to make Amadeus' code snippet work, but didn't understand 100% what was wrong with my code in the first place. The insight really helps!

Comment: I have another question actually, since you seem knowledgeable on the subject. Is there a simple way for me to run this same code, but with the array being of type char or bool?

Comment: @Wil It's rather type-agnostic. It'll work on any type of value, as long as the `if (a[i])` check is only expected to detect between "0/false/nothing" and "1/true/something". Otherwise, simply change that to `if (a[i] == whatever_condition)` to filter out the right values.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot. Thanks again!